# Doxygen can't expand AUTOSAR macros

Tags: c, doxygen, autosar

I am using Doxygen v1.8.9.1 to analyze an AUTOSAR C code.
AUTOSAR code has some macros to define variables and functions. Something like this:

```
#define P2VAR(ptrtype, memclass, ptrclass)  ptrtype *
```

I tried to change the following configurations:

```
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING
MACRO_EXPANSION     
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF  
EXPAND_AS_DEFINED   
SKIP_FUNCTION_MACROS
```

and no matter what I do, it doesn't recognize the functions and variables defined using these macros. Rather, it sees multiple functions with the same name.

for example:
if I have the following code:

```
typedef P2VAR( uint8, AUTOMATIC, DATA_LOCATION)  var_1;
typedef P2VAR( uint8, AUTOMATIC, DATA_LOCATION)  var_2;
typedef P2VAR( uint8, AUTOMATIC, DATA_LOCATION)  var_3;
```

It will not see 3 variables of type uint8 names var_1, var_2, var_3
but it sees 3 functions with the same name P2VAR

example from the xml output:

[image]

anyone have seen this before and was able to fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by "it sees 3 functions"? With the preceeding `typedef` in those lines that confuses me.

Comment: Just for an experiment (or to make the problem description more pointed), what happens if you insert the macro definition right before the use?

Comment: @RubberBee It shows them as functions in the output (see the screenshot added to the question).

Comment: I have also tried other macros where the definition is just before the usage. I get the same outcome. that is why I suspected I have some global configuration problem.

Comment: Version 1.8.9.1 is a bit old (January 2015), the current version is 1.8.20.  What happens when you use the current version?

Comment: In your xml output I see `FUNC`, `FLS_FUNC`, I cannot relate this in any way to the code example you gave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I tried a simple code, it works fine just as mentioned in the answer by @albert but it still didn't work on a large code.

What works for me is to add the macros in the PREDEFINED configuration as follows:

```
PREDEFINED             = "FUNC(rettype,memclass)=rettype" \
                         "P2VAR(ptrtype,memclass,ptrclass)=ptrtype *" \
                         "VAR(type,memclass)=type"
```

Comment: In my previous comment (with the question) I wrote: "Version 1.8.9.1 is a bit old (January 2015), the current version is 1.8.20. What happens when you use the current version? " Is this version correct? what happens when using the 1.8.20 version?

Answer (score 1):

In case I use your code:

```
#define P2VAR(ptrtype, memclass, ptrclass)  ptrtype *


typedef P2VAR( uint8, AUTOMATIC, DATA_LOCATION)  var_1;
typedef P2VAR( uint8, AUTOMATIC, DATA_LOCATION)  var_2;
typedef P2VAR( uint8, AUTOMATIC, DATA_LOCATION)  var_3;
```

and as doxygen configuration file:

```
QUIET=YES
EXTRACT_ALL=YES
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING=YES
MACRO_EXPANSION  =YES
EXPAND_AS_DEFINED=YES
GENERATE_XML=YES
```

I see `P2VAR` only once in the definitions part and once in the index (and of course in the code part).
I see this in case of doxygen version 1.8.20 as well as with version 1.8.9.1

Comment: Thanks for your help.
When I tried it with simple one or 2 files it works fine. but it didn't work with a big code base (at least for the AUTOSAR macros and a few others).
It only works for me when I add the macros definition in the PREDEFINED tag. I will put it in a separate answer to be more visible.

Comment: In my previous comment (with the question) I wrote: "Version 1.8.9.1 is a bit old (January 2015), the current version is 1.8.20. What happens when you use the current version? " Is this version correct? what happens when using the 1.8.20 version?

Comment: yes, I am using v1.8.9.1 as this is the version recommended for the project. I tried with v1.8.20 and I get the same behavior.

Comment: Strange, would be interesting to see an exact case where it goes wrong. I don't know who recommended 1.8.9.1, 5 years ago this was OK, but I think nowadays it would be better to use 1.8.20 to use also newer features build into doxygen.